# Determine whether UITableViewCell is editing from "swipe" or "self.editButton"

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm trying to determine whether a UITableViewCell subclass is in edit mode from a user's swipe (in which case I don't need to indent my subviews) or from the user pressing the "Edit" button associated with the UITableViewController. (In which case I do.)

I know it's possible from a cell's perspective, since the `self.textLabel` view automatically indents properly. I have tried:

```
-(void)layoutSubviews {
   [super layoutSubviews];

   CGRect labelFrame = self.textLabel.frame;
   labelFrame.origin.x += 5;
   myCustomUILabel.frame = labelFrame;
}
```

But my custom label does not properly indent. (Though the `self.textLabel` view does?)

I would like to avoid the following:

- Providing the cells with a reference to the parent table.
- Overriding methods in the UITableViewController class to let the cells know whether they are being edited individually or the entire table is editing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can override `willTransitionToState:` in your `UITableViewCell` subclass. When the "Edit" button is pressed the state will be `UITableViewCellStateShowingEditControlMask`(=1) and when swiping it will be `UITableViewCellStateShowingDeleteConfirmationMask`(=2).

Comment: Close, but the tricky part is that when clicking the "Edit" button then tapping the "-" button for a row, it transitions to state 2. What I want to do is determine whether that "-" button is showing, so I can move a view on the left farther off screen. (Which isn't required when swiping.)

Comment: If you have clicked "Edit" and then taps the "-" button the state mask will be 3.

Comment: Wow, sure enough. Leave it to apple to only document states 0, 1, and 2 in the header file. (There is absolutely no mention of state 3, but I debugged and sure enough, you're right. Thanks!) I wonder if state 3 is supposed to indicate *both* state 1 and state 2, thus 1+2=3.

Comment: Since the states are called masks I would assume you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

You should not be doing the indentation manually. The UITableViewCell will do it for you!

All you have to do is make sure that you add your subviews to '`contentView`' of the UITableViewCell. This is the reason why `self.textLabel` indents properly as you have identified.

Look at the documentation of contentView property for a UITableViewCell:

The content view of a UITableViewCell object is the default superview for content displayed by the cell. If you want to customize cells by simply adding additional views, you should add them to the content view **so they will be positioned appropriately as the cell transitions into and out of editing mode**.